# Forms Authentication with JASIG CAS Custom operation after logon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cas

It's my First question here so i apologize for my english :)

we are building MVC 4 application with authentication made by [Jasig CAS SSO](http://www.jasig.org/cas).

It works pretty good but i need to do custom action after authentication of user.

Steps should look like:

1. User goes to our site to HomeController which is decorated by AuthorizeAttribute
2. Controller redirects user to CAS
3. User pass his username and password
4. CAS properly authenticates user and redirects to our site
5. (here goes custom action) After logon we build up Session (get user parameters from DB and put them in to chache and etc)

action 5. is run only once after successful logon! every next request skips this step.

I have read documentation of CAS and MSDN about forms authentication but i couldn't any information.

I found that i could extend AuthorizeAttribute and override AuthorizeCore method but it is ran every request.

thanks for help

Comment: what is JASIG CAS SSO ?

Comment: It allows single sign on for many aplications( you put your credentials only once and you are logged in every application configured) in your company
 more information here - http://www.jasig.org/cas

Comment: make a public proj on github and share it with me and I will fix it on Github.

Comment: It won't be easy task :) i can't publish because its commercial project. ill try to make prototype.

maybe u can say what should i do ? write own AuthorizeAttribute or sth with specific logic ?

Comment: I don't know what this CAS do. I suggest you to search for openID provide on Nuget and Github. you will find many useful according to your requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself. Maybe there are better resolutions but this one makes what i wanted.

To make some custom action after logon in Jasig CAS you need to implement

`protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)`

in `Global.asax`

sample code:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //must check if user is authenticated (this method can be called before authentication) 
            if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Context.Session != null && Context.Session["IsLogged"] == null)
            {
               Context.Session.Add("YourKey", YourData);
               Context.Session.Add("IsLogged", true);
            }

        }
```

Probably the same approach could be used in standard forms authentication if needed